# Android Saripaar-v2 OR annotation

Tags: android, validation, saripaar

So I have a field:

```
@NotEmpty
@Email
@Or
@Pattern(regex = "\\+?64(\\d{8,10})")
private EditText mETUser;
```

Basically, what I'm after is: The field can't be empty and must contain either a valid email OR a valid phone number (the Pattern.)

The OR annotation seems to be ignored though. If I enter a valid email, I get a failure on the `@Pattern` rule, and a valid phone number fails on the `@Email` rule.

I create the validator in the onCreate of my activity:

```
mValidator = new Validator(this);
mValidator.setValidationListener(this);
```

And validate the fields in an onClickListner with

```
mValidator.validate(false);
```

My callbacks are pretty basic at the moment:

```
@Override
public void onValidationSucceeded() {
    Log.d(TAG,"Validation passed");
}

@Override
public void onValidationFailed(List<ValidationError> errors) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Validation failed: ");
    for (ValidationError e : errors) {
        Log.d(TAG, "\tError: " + e.toString());
    }
}
```

I must be missing something, but I can't find any documentation on the OR annotation.

Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry, I goofed up. `@Optional` and `@Or` annotations were planned for the `2.1.0` release. They were not meant to be in the jars for `2.0.x`.

Comment: Ha ha ha, I wondered if that was the case. Didn't seem to be plumbed in at all! Well, thanks for letting me know. Any suggestions in the meantime that don't involve a custom annotation, or is that pretty much my option?

Comment: You could use a `QuickRule`, less arduous than a custom annotation and register it with the validator. `mValidator.put(emailOrPhoneNumberEditText, emailOrPhoneNumberQuickRule)`. You can keep watching these issues - https://github.com/ragunathjawahar/android-saripaar/issues/61 and https://github.com/ragunathjawahar/android-saripaar/issues/120